# GCC, clang/llvm, exe file size

Tags: gcc, clang, exe

Windows 10, LLVM 7, GCC 8.1, Visual studio 2019.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char exe[1000000] = {};
int n = 0;
int filesize;
void read() {
    int pointer = 0;
    cin >> filesize;
    fstream f;
    f.open("s.exe", ios::in | ios::app | ios::binary);
    f.seekp(pointer, ios::beg);
    while (pointer < filesize) {
        f.read((char*)&n,sizeof(char));
        exe[pointer] = n;
        pointer += 1;
    }
    f.close();
}
void showMassive(){
    int pointer = 0;
    while(pointer<filesize){
    cout << pointer << ":" << (unsigned int8_t)exe[pointer] << endl;
    pointer+=1;
    }
}
void showAssembler(){

}
void write() {
    int pointer = 0;
    fstream f;
    f.open("s1.exe", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
    f.seekp(pointer, ios::beg);
    while (pointer < filesize) {
        n=exe[pointer];
        pointer += 1;
        f.write((char*)&n,sizeof(char));
    }
    f.close();
}
void MachineCodeOptimizer(){
    //some code
    exe[1031] += 1;//just for example
}
int main(){
    read();
    showMassive();
    showAssembler();
    MachineCodeOptimizer();
    write();
    return 0;
}
```

- this code. Clang creates an exe file 312 kilobytes size at best (-O1 key). GCC creates 66 KB size exe anyway. What happens? Why so difference between compilers? I look at machine code, but dont understand. Now i tried visual studio 2019 - 26 KB! Visual studio 2019 showing result close to assembler(in file size).

Comment: 1. Which compiler version, windows version, clang version, gcc version? 2. Have you try GodBolt on these? 3. Did you look in side the binary with Microsoft's executable-format-related tools?

Comment: windows 10 last, llvm 7.0, minw64 gcc 8.1.

Comment: No, i  dont looked machine code and dont tryed use godbolt

Comment: Please update the link to point to the specific commit. If someone else finds this the code may have changed making it difficult to see what's going on

Comment: @lifehack: Put the version data in your question.

Comment: i already did it

Comment: @lifehack he meant putting the code here. Each question should be self-contained. Link to external resources may become invalid someday

Answer (score 0):

`Clang` and `GCC` are two completely independent compilers. When you write code in your source language, you only specify *what* you want the machine to execute, not *how* it should do that. Compilers are free in choosing their ways to get there, as long as they stay within the limits that are specified by your source language. So it's not surprising that the two resulting executables differ in file size. Also the chosen instructions by the two compilers might differ a lot (or completely) since there are, for example, a dozen different ways to represent loops in machine code (incl. taking advantage of parallel execution of the target processor ... or not). You might want to check out Matt Godbolt's talk from 2017 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4); this can give you a short but exhaustive introduction in what compilers actually do (for you) behind the scenes.

Comment: I know it. But gcc code around same performance as llvm code and same time gcc code 5 times less. And at the same time, the creators of LLVM talk about leading.

Comment: New result: visual studio 2019 - less than 30 KB!